# What is the best approach for send time optimization?

Tags: classification, time-series, regression, statistics, theory

I could no find a lot information about how the companies doabout send time optimization, either for push notifications or email campaigs. having historical data about clicks and sends what would be your approarch?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best method to find optimal send time is A/B testing. Send the same emails/notification at different times to different people. Then see if one group tends to open the emails more than another group.